# monit: monitoring certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, monit

I am currently trying to keep watch of my systems certificates to make sure I get alerting 30 days before expiring. As an example I took google.com and monitoring its certificates. Looking at monitrc file I have added this:

```
check host google.com with address google.com
            if failed
                    port 443
                    protocol https
                    with ssl options {verify: enable}
                    certificate valid > 1095 days
            then alert
```

When I restart monit I get the error there is no service called google.com

Answer (score 0):

When setting up new monit config or change/edit current config, should reload first to make sure monit reinitializing the daemon

#### Reproduce issue

```
# Edit monit config
root@home:~# vim /etc/monit/conf-enabled/test

# Restart right way will fail
root@home:~# monit restart all
There is no service named "google.com"

# Logs
[CEST Sep 12 19:16:29] info     : 'home' trying to restart
[CEST Sep 12 19:16:29] info     : 'home' restart action done
[CEST Sep 12 19:17:09] info     : 'home' restart on user request
[CEST Sep 12 19:17:09] error    : HttpRequest: error -- client [::1]: HTTP/1.0 400 There is no service named "google.com"
[CEST Sep 12 19:17:09] error    : There is no service named "google.com"
```

#### Solution

```
# Edit monit config
root@home:~# vim /etc/monit/conf-enabled/test

# Reload to reinitialize monit
root@home:~# monit reload
Reinitializing monit daemon

root@home:~# monit status
Monit 5.25.2 uptime: 24m

Remote Host 'google.com'
  status                       OK
  monitoring status            Monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  port response time           878.069 ms to google.com:443 type TCP/IP using TLS (certificate valid for 69 days) protocol HTTP
  data collected               Thu, 12 Sep 2019 19:24:06
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also run periodic tests with a software like [Overseer](https://github.com/cmaster11/overseer), and receive notifications using a [Notify17](https://notify17.net) notification template (see the sample [recipe](https://notify17.net/recipes/overseer/)).

You could use a test rule like:

```
https://myurl.com/path must run https
```

Or

```
https://myurl.com/path must run ssl
```

These rules evaluate if a website is reachable over SSL and if the certificate will expire soon (you can see more options in the [source code](https://github.com/cmaster11/overseer/blob/b9682e1a3d5603d83172318dc010c5fe570bfd62/protocols/ssl_probe.go#L8)).

P.S. To have an easy start with Overseer, you can check out the [Kubernetes deployment example](https://github.com/cmaster11/overseer/tree/master/example-kubernetes).

Comment: not really related to the question, maybe it's a spam answer